# Can I install Ubuntu 12.10 in a Toshiba Satellite C645D?

Tags: toshiba-satellite, toshiba

I am wondering if my drivers will work. I really need my webcam but I don't know if it will be okay. Can someone help me? Sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: I would try running the LiveCD and seeing if it works.  If you need to install some software for it run `sudo apt-get install cheese` and run it from the dash.

Answer (score 2):

I guess so. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 x64 in my Toshiba Satellite C665. It works very fine.